# Error in my Jhipster Project when i want Generating a WAR file

Tags: maven, jhipster

I created a project with JHipster, but I'm finding a error in my Project when i want generating a WAR file, it happens when I use the command ./mvnw -Pprod package.

```
Results :
Failed tests: 
  EstabelecimentoResourceIntTest.createEstabelecimento:190 expected:    <19[69-12-31T20:00-04:00[America/Santarem]]> but was:<19[70-01-  01T00:00Z[UTC]]>
  EstabelecimentoResourceIntTest.updateEstabelecimento:311 expected:<2016-11-04T1[4:26:30-03:00[America/Santarem]]> but was:<2016-11-04T1[7:26:30Z[UTC]]>
Tests in error: 
EstabelecimentoResourceIntTest.getEstabelecimento:229 » NestedServletRequest ...
EstabelecimentoResourceIntTest.getNonExistingEstabelecimento:255 » NestedServlet

Tests run: 52, Failures: 2, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------   ---------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:18 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-04T14:26:33-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/326M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project acaipdejhipster: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/geovane/NetBeansProjects/acaipdejhipster/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml. Also we would need the complete stack trace. Run the command `mvn clean install -X`. This would produce the detailed stack trace. Shere the stack trace with us then.

Comment: This sounds like there are 2 errors when executing your Tests. You can try to find the errors in the EstabelecimentoResourceIntTest file or just skipping the tests using `./mvnw -Pprod -DskipTests package`

Comment: Please provide more information using `yo jhipster:info`. As said above, you have 2 tests failing on expected dates. Could be a duplicate of https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4373